# Prevent creation of new model object if another one was created less than 24 hours ago in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to prevent a model object to be created, if another one was created say less than 24 hours ago.

There is a trick however. This rule does not apply to ALL model objects and will dependent on a set of rule laid out in a different model.

To be more specific, if `Venue_1` has a `RuleModel` set to 1, then when creating a new `MyModel object` the database would check if a previous `MyModel object` had been created within less than 1 day ago. If true then new `MyModel object` is not saved, if false `MyModel object` is saved.

However if Venue_2 does not have any rule, then MyModel objects can be created without any time restrictions.

After some research on this forum, it looks like I need to override the save function in the model.

This is not working at present. Not error message.

**models.py**

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name",max_length=100, blank=True)

class RuleModel(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, null = True, blank= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="loylaty_points_rule", null = True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    timeframe = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='timeframe during which more points cannot be reclaimed', null=True, blank=True)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    add_points = models.DecimalField(name = 'add_points', null = True, blank=True, default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=50)
    qr_code_venue = models.ImageField(upload_to='qr_codes_venue', blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        rule_model = RuleModel()
        for rulemodel in rule_model:
            if rulemodel.timeframe:
                try:
                    date_from = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=rulemodel.timeframe)
                    MyModel.objects.get(timestamp__gte=date_from)
                    #raise some save error
                except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
                    super(MyModel,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
       last_obj = YourModelName.objects.last()
       if last_obj and timezone.now() - last_obj.created_at < timezone.timedelta(hours=24):
          raise ValidationError('Your Message')
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Note:** Your Model must have created_at or updated_at fields

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Unless I am wrong, this answer would only work if the last object was also the object I wanted to make the timedelta comparaison too. In my case, there can be many objects between the 2 I am looking to compare.  I suppose this could work if I was to add a filter based on the venue after `last()` which would be `last().filter(venue=request.user.userprofile.venue)`. What do you think?

Comment: i didn't get your point

Comment: hi there, I was trying to explain your answer wasnt exactly working in my case as I needed  to (1) make it work with data contained in another model (see `RuleModel`) and (2) take into account that the latest model object might not always be the one I need to search for and some filters might be required. Maybe overriding the save method was too advance for me. I am working on another alternative solution (with views and templates) and trying to use some bits of your answers to make it work :)